# Tutorial for an application both in iphone 4-inch and 3.5-inch retina display

Tags: iphone

Please suggest any tutorial for an application both in iphone 4-inch and 3.5-inch retina display. Whether i ll do it by xib or programatically ??

Comment: Tutorial on what? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your Autosizing for your view in your xib file like this :

[image]

By code :

```
// Define for know if it's an iPhone 5 or not
#define IS_IPHONE5()    ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set the view frame
    self.view.frame = (IS_IPHONE5() ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568) : CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480));
}
```